# MVC and graphics component

Tags: java, model-view-controller, graphics

Im trying to create a game in Java that follows the MVC pattern. My problem is that i can't figure out a good way to pass the game map stored in the Model to the paint component in the View.

A very simplified version of my code:

Model

```
public class Model {    

    //0,0,200,200,0.... are read from a file and stored in a List 
    //inside the model.     
    private List<Integer> gameMap;   

    public Model(){
        gameMap = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 

    }
```

View

```
public class View extends JFrame{
    private class GameBoard extends JComponent{                 
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

            //Now I need the values from the List in the Model to my 
            //View for the g.drawRect methods

            g.drawRect(0, 0, 200, 200);                 
        }
    }
```

Controller

```
public class Controller {

    public Controller(View view, Model model) {

    }
```

The easiest way would of course be to just have a have a static List in the view and do a Model.gameMap... but that would break the MVC pattern.

Would it still be MVC if I kept a copy of the gameMap in the View by doing something like this in the Controller?

```
view.gameMap = model.gameMap;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to follow the MVC pattern, **the View cannot have any reference to the Model**.

In order not to break the MVC, the Controller (that will read the Model) has to provide that information to the View.

---

Your code is really simplified, but a correct example (respecting the MVC) would be:

*Model*

```
public class Model {    
    
    //GameMap info is read from a file and stored in a List 
    //inside the model.     
    private List<Integer> gameMap;   
    
    public Model(){
        gameMap = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
        //Read file and fill gameMap
    }

    public List<Integer> getGameMap(){
        return gameMap;
    }
}
```

*View*

```
public class View extends JFrame{

    private Controller controller;

    public View(Controller controller){
        this.controller = controller;
    }

    private class GameBoard extends JComponent{                 
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

            //Now I need the values from the List in the Model to my 
            //View for the g.drawRect methods

            List<Integer> gameMapInfo = controller.getGameMap();
            //Perform custom drawing using this object's values
            //g.drawRect()...
        }

    }
```

*Controller*

```
public class Controller {

    private View view;
    private Model model;

    public Controller(View view, Model model) {
        this.view = view;
        this.model = model;
    }

    public List<Integer> getGameMap(){
        return model.getGameMap();
    }
```

The View saves a reference of the Controller, and when it's time to paint asks the Controller for the information it needs to do so. The controller asks the Model, and returns the information back to the View.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply pass the draw context by declaring such a methode

```
private Object drawContext;
public void updateDrawContext(Object drawContext){
    this.drawContext = drawContext;
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    drawContext(g);
    g.drawRect(0, 0, 200, 200);                 
}

private void drawContext(Graphics g){
    // your custom draw code
    // just an example, not real code:
    for(OPbject o: drawContext.getItems() ){ // your custom draw code
        o.draw(g);
    }
}
```

ideally you would declare the methode `void updateDrawContext(Object drawContext)` in an `interface MVCView`

Comment: ideally you would pass a `List<Drawable>` not a mere Object as shown in my answer. `Drawable` would be an interface that lets you `void draw(Graphics g)` something.